# Generic call of overloaded methods

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

i have a problem with C# generics when trying to call overloaded methods. I would appreciate if you could help me.

i call `Example.test()`

```
public class Example
{

    private String printObject(Object o)
    {
       //this is the one that is called
    }

    private String printObject(String o)
    {
      //this is the one I expect to be called
    }

    private void callPrint<T>(Object o)
    {
            if (o is T)
            {
                T tmp;
                tmp = (T)o;
                data = _printObject(tmp);
            }
    }

    public String foo(Object o)
    {
        callPrint<String>(o);
    }

    public static void test()
    { 
         String test="Test";
         foo(test);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't `void callPrint<T>(T item)` make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

Well, which is called has to be determined once for all types. Your `String printObject(String o)` will only be valid if `T` is a string - otherwise not, so the compiler cannot bind the generic method to this statically typed method.